# Java App started as service on 64bit environment, but doesn't work

Tags: service, 64-bit, java

I have installed 64bit jre on my pc (starts in mixed mode), then i compiled my Java application in 64bit mode. It starts prefectly and works fine as stand alone application.

Then I install it as service using a JSL.EXE (with jsl.ini) and it starts again fine, **BUT doesn't work**: doesnt answer (this is a small server) and writes nothing into a log-file.

The same application works fine as a service if i compile it with jre 32bit and install as a service in 32bit environment.

thanks

Comment: How are the system `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` env variables configured? They are probably different from your logged on user's.

Comment: Post your information on how you configured as a service or try giving allevated privileges and check.

Comment: You don't need to recompile your code to switch between 32-bit and 64-bit JVMs. Use the same JAR in each case to ensure you are running the same thing. I suspect JSL.EXE doesn'ty handle 64-bit JVMs and IMHO its not started until you see its initial logs correctly.

Comment: Note: 64-bit support has only been added as of the latest release. Do you have the latest version, even so it may not be 100%. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I have just run jsl.exe -debug and saw everithing, what has been happen. The wrong JRE was taken by jsl... and i schould also define a jvmtype parameter in jsl.ini.... and i didn't know that jsl64.exe schould be used for 64bit java apps (apps with 64bit SWT)

[java]
jvmtype=server,client,hotspot,classic

thanks